How to parse datetime from the format "Sep 5, 2024 12:38:18 PM"
I'm trying to parse the datetime from the string
"Sep 5, 2024 12:38:18 PM"

in BigQuery, but I'm getting the error:
Failed to parse input string "Sep 5, 2024 12:38:18 PM"

I've tried
select parse_datetime("%b %e %Y %I:%M:%S %p", "Sep 5, 2024 12:38:18 PM")

As well as a few other format strings, expecting to get:
"2024-09-05 12:38:18" 

but they all came out with the same error.

try %d instead of %e Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time (admittedly, the documentation is strange ... they say %d means the day of month is preceded by a space for single digits, which I have no idea what they mean by "a space" - usually with date parsing you are either parsing a number with a leading zero or without the leading zero). I suppose if worse comes to worse and we take this documentation at its word, then try %b%d

You are very close, only a comma after the day is missing in your format string. Try
select parse_datetime("%b %e, %Y %I:%M:%S %p", "Sep 5, 2024 12:38:18 PM")

